# Error "Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list" al hacer OpenCV+Unity build en Android

Tags: unity, opencv

Estoy intentando hacer un juego usando OpenCV+Unity en Android.
El juego funciona bien en Unity, pero al hacer la build para android salta el error "Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list", y el juego crashea.

Lo estoy intentando con la demo que viene en los assets y salta el mismo problema, por lo que debe ser algun tipo de incompatibilidad que no entiendo (porque en teoria el asset es compatible con builds Android)

Lo único que utilizo es el asset anterior y la librería OpenCVSharp (a parte de las basicas de Unity y UnityEngine).

Estoy usando un movil Xiaomi Redmi 8A, con MIUI12.
¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, estamos en al version de SO en ESPAÑOL, te recomiendo [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/542329/edit) la pregunta y ponerla en español, de lo contrario sera cerrada.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Perdona, ya esta traducida. Pensaba que la había posteado en la version inglesa.

Comment: Procura proveer más detalles a tu pregunta (y traduce el título también). Actualmente, es difícil que se pueda reproducir el error. Lee [ask].